# Extent Report: Klov: How to limit the visibility of TestCases from other projects, when viewing test case history/Search

Tags: extent, extentreports

I am facing issues while comparing the test cases in History, as same Test case is referred in Multiple Projects. Currently the KLOV is fetching the test case data from all the projects, and display in history section.

Is there any way we can limit the visibility of test case at a project level ?

KLOV Version: 0.1.1
Extent: 3.1.5

Thanks,
~Sundan

Comment: Are You creating different Projects, or are all in one, but with different testruns?

Comment: I am using different projects, which contain the same test case.